# My input data cannot be updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql, input

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/221/mysystem.jpg/

Anyone can help me, I stuck right now at first column, which is Total Pending Column, I cannot change the data of "200" at frontend page, I just can edit it manually at backend page which is at phpmyadmin, it's difficult to my user to change the data at the front side, BUT it make me confused why the other column can be able to edit at the front? Just only the Total Pending  column cannot be edit, when I click update button, the others updated except first column.

Please help me..

Herewith my Update PHP Coding

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE sr1 SET appt_today=%s, partial_complete=%s, full_complete=%s, return_technical=%s, return_customer=%s, return_cancel=%s, cancel=%s, reappt=%s, focus=%s WHERE total_pending=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['appt_today'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['partial_complete'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['full_complete'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['return_technical'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['return_customer'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['return_cancel'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['cancel'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['reappt'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['focus'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['total_pending'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $pods) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "main.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}

mysql_select_db($database_pods, $pods);
$query_sr1 = "SELECT * FROM sr1";
$sr1 = mysql_query($query_sr1, $pods) or die(mysql_error());
$row_sr1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sr1);
$totalRows_sr1 = mysql_num_rows($sr1);
?>
```

And Here is my Coding for input data, which I state above is "200" but cannot be update.

```
<input name="total_pending" type="text" class="style6" onKeyPress="return checkIt(event)" value="<?php echo $row_sr1['total_pending']; ?>" size="3" maxlength="3" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query doesn't update any value called `total_pending`:

```
UPDATE
  sr1
SET
  appt_today=%s,
  partial_complete=%s,
  full_complete=%s,
  return_technical=%s,
  return_customer=%s,
  return_cancel=%s,
  cancel=%s,
  reappt=%s,
  focus=%s
WHERE
  total_pending=%s
```

You use `total_pending` to find the record(s) you want to update, but you don't actually update that value in that/those record(s).

Keep in mind that in order to update the same field you're using to find the record(s), you'll need to include that parameter twice with two different values.  One for the new value to which it should update and one for the existing value which it uses to find the record(s).

For example:

```
UPDATE
  sr1
SET
  appt_today=%s,
  partial_complete=%s,
  full_complete=%s,
  return_technical=%s,
  return_customer=%s,
  return_cancel=%s,
  cancel=%s,
  reappt=%s,
  focus=%s,
  total_pending=%s -- update this field as well
WHERE
  total_pending=%s
```

**Edit:** To clarify a bit more for you, the first thing you'll want to do is add another field to the form to track a separate `total_pending` value.  This is because you'll need two of them for the update, one representing the original value (for the `WHERE` clause) and one representing the new value.  So you'll want to add something like this:

```
<input name="total_pending_original" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_sr1['total_pending']; ?>" />
```

Then, using the updated query I gave you above, you'll also need to add a new parameter.  So the total query/parameter code should look like this:

```
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE sr1 SET appt_today=%s, partial_complete=%s, full_complete=%s, return_technical=%s, return_customer=%s, return_cancel=%s, cancel=%s, reappt=%s, focus=%s, total_pending=%s WHERE total_pending=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['appt_today'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['partial_complete'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['full_complete'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['return_technical'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['return_customer'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['return_cancel'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['cancel'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['reappt'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['focus'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['total_pending'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['total_pending_original'], "int"));
```

Also, one thing you should note is that you should not being mysql_* functions anymore.  PHP is deprecating them.  Take a look at the big red box indicating that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: can you rewrite back the exactly code which can update all the data?

Comment: @mastersuse: Sorry, are you being sarcastic?  It's difficult to tell in a text-only medium.  What are you asking?  The reason the data isn't being updated is because you're explicitly not updating it.  If you want to update it, include it in your SQL query.

Comment: hi david, actually I'm not good in PHP, so can you help me where I give you my coding by email and you fixed it for me? just a help. I have been stuck for 3 month.

Comment: @mastersuse: See my updated answer.  I don't really provide email-based free consulting services, but I'm happy to help with the question and answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi david, thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it, I love coding but I'm not sure that I'm good in PHP.

Comment: @mastersuse: Well, one might argue that PHP itself isn't very good :)  There's no substitute for practice and experience, so keep it up and good luck!

Comment: hey david! guess what, thanks so much again for your guidance and flow instruction, I got the answer, I made it.. :)